# How to transform the image?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, transformation, emgucv

[image: original image]

You can see the lanes are askew. I want to make the lanes perpendicular.

I used **Photoshop's perspective transformation function**, got the result:

[image: after perspective transformation]

Although the lanes are vertical now, the cars in the far end become large, the cars in the near end become so small. That is not what I　want.

I tried **Photoshop's warp function**. Photoshop gave me 8 control points and I finally got my ideal result.

[image: What I want]

What is the name of that kind of transformation?

How to do the transformation programmatically? I'm using C# + EmguCV(OpenCV)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It is called [Radial Distortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29). It is commonly fixed by [Browns model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29#cite_note-brown-1). [Here](http://www.creativepro.com/article/photoshop-how-to-eliminate-barrel-distortion-caused-by-camera-lenses) is a tutorial on how to fix it using Photoshop.

[image]

Be aware that in your case, you should **first** fix the radial distortion, and only then do a projective transformation (Homography), since radial distortion is a property of the lens, whereas the projective transformation is a property of the world you are taking a look at.

Comment: It is very helpful to know it is radical distortion. I learned that opencv can fix the distortion using camera matrix and distCoeffs. To calculate the two parameters, the chessboard method may be used. But the camera taken the image is not accessible. Any suggestions?

Comment: @LoveRight, try finding the coefficients manually on image that contains lines.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from correcting for radial distortion, the perspective can be corrected by applying a homography transform (assuming the road is flat)